# Error : Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have created `Oracle ADF` project and tried to run. but i got below error.

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
"C:\Documents and Settings\ABC\Application Data\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd"
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -jrockit
CLASSPATH=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Java\JDK17~1.0\lib\tools.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\native;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Java\JDK17~1.0\jre\bin;C:\Java\JDK17~1.0\bin;C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\LOCALS~1\Temp\sfx113.tmp\jre160_05\bin;D:\Program Files\WANdisco\uberSVN\bin;D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\WinSCP\;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Java\JDK17~1.0\bin\java -jrockit   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\LOCALS~1\Temp\trustStore2528913390651243248.jks -Doracle.jdeveloper.adrs=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dcommon.components.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1 -Djrockit.optfile=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=\- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\DOCUME~1\ABC\APPLIC~1\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.1\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1112\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -jrockit
Process exited.
```

what should i do for solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JDK 6 - JDK 7 is not supported right now to run the integrated WebLogic in JDeveloper.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hotspot JVM, you should remove `-jrockit` java option, since it is for [JRockit JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/intro.htm).

Comment: i'm using client JVM. and i'm not added any options to jvm.